# Connecting to a VPN on a remote linux server (VPS) fails

Tags: networking, server, ssh, vpn, openvpn

I've been trying to connect to a VPN through my Ubuntu [VPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server), but every time I try, the server shuts down.

Perhaps the connection blocks the ssh, and all the traffic when I try to connect?  I tried connecting with a VPN to a [Dedicated Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedicated_hosting_service) with Ubuntu Linux, first 18.04 then 16.04, and to a virtual private server with Ubuntu Linux. Both failed, so at least I know there's no difference.

I just get disconnected and I can't connect to my VPS unless I reboot it. Is there any way I could set up a VPN on my VPS or at least is there a way to change my VPS internal IP multiple times?

So I'm using the NordVPN .deb application. After I successfully install it, I connect with my password and email, then I use ''`nordvpn connect`'' (sometimes I specify the server which I want to connect to, for example `nordvpn connect es/br/us/etc`). It says `Connecting..` then the linux server just freezes, and in about 10 seconds I get disconnected.

But I didn't stop there. I tried using NordVPN manually via OpenVPN. I installed the packages, and the same thing happened, after I connected, the VPS just dropped, and I had to reboot it.

I don't have any errors to show since it's just connecting - failing - shutting down. It might also be the service I use for VPS however I'm really desperate to find a service that allows me to use VPN. I really need it for my project and In 2 attempts all failed.

Please let me know if you need further information in the comments and I will edit the question. I might have missed some things since it's pretty late, tried to work this out all day.

Comment: WhIch release of Ubuntu did you try bare metal, and in the VPS? Can you try an alternate version?

Comment: I tried this on Ubuntu 18.04.  I'm not sure what do you mean as an alternate version. @K7AAY

Comment: Fer exx, 16.04, 19.10

Comment: I have tried on 16.04 too.

Answer (score 0):

the server doesn't shut down or freeze, it gets disconnected from the shh because the traffic is being forwarded from the vpn ip.
I reboot multiple times my server trying to connect with a vpn on, but the vpn was starting with the system reboot.
I realize that it was still possible to connect to the server using the web console of linode.
I checked for the vpn service status and it was connected through US-C UDP (443). Typing:

```
curl http://ipinfo.io/ip
```

I checked for my ip. It was a different ip.

I think if you need to change VPS internal IP multiple times you could use a firewall to be able to connect to the ssh while vpn is connected, or you could use a shh script to disconnect  the vpn once the task you need the new ip for is completed.